# How Can I Merge a Single<List<List<T>>> Into a List<T> with RxJava 2?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

What I want to do is hit an endpoint to get a list of users, that returns `Single<List<User>>`. Next, I want to grab the first three users and hit another endpoint to get all of their posts `Single<List<Post>>`. Finally I want to display a `Toast` that has the *total number of posts* for all of the first 3 users.

I've been able to achieve it with the `flatten()` function available in Kotlin. However, I'd like to know how to do this using only RxJava 2. Is it possible? Thanks.

```
...

getPostsForFirstThreeUsers()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        { posts -> toast("There are: ${posts.flatten().size} posts") },
        { ex -> Timber.e(ex, "there was an error processing the request") }
              )



fun getFirstThreeUsers(): Flowable<User> {
    return getAllUsers()
            .flattenAsFlowable { users -> users }
            .doOnNext { Timber.i("a user: ${it.username}") }
            .take(3)
}

fun getPostsForFirstThreeUsers(): Single<List<List<Post>>> {
    return getFirstThreeUsers()
            .flatMapSingle { api.getUsersPosts(it.id) }
            .doOnNext { Timber.i("number of posts: ${it.size}") }
            .toList()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with this solution, which allows me to have access to the entire `List` of `Post` objects. Thanks for the direction.

```
fun getPostsForFirstThreeUsers(): Single<MutableList<Post>> {
        return getFirstThreeUsers()
                .flatMapSingle { api.getUsersPosts(it.id) }
                .doOnNext { Timber.i("number of posts: ${it.size}") }
                .flatMapIterable { it }
                .doOnNext { Timber.i("the post: $it") }
                .toList()
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're only looking for the total number of posts, you could just `flatmap` the lists to a stream and then `count`. The flat-mapping will not guarantee order, but flattens the list of list into a single stream.

```
getPostsForFirstThreeUsers()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatmapObservable(Observable::fromIterable)
    .flatmap(Observable::fromIterable)
    .count()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        { count -> toast("There are: ${count} posts") },
        { ex -> Timber.e(ex, "there was an error processing the request") }
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this but I think you can do this with `flatmap` and `reduce` (or `collect`). probably something's like:

```
getAllUsers()
  .take(3)
  .flatMap { api.getUsersPosts(it.id) }
  .map { it.size }
  .reduce(0) { acc, e -> acc + e }
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(
    { posts -> toast("There are: ${posts.flatten().size} posts") },
    { ex -> Timber.e(ex, "there was an error processing the request") }
   )
```